# xmlhttp request to heroku php application backend

Tags: php, heroku, xmlhttprequest

I recently set up a heroku php app and have it returning data based on http requests.  It works with requests, however, xmlhttp requests do not work.  Why would this be?

```
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    //This is never called!!! Why?
                    displaySpot.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is the page calling this code served from the same domain as the PHP backend? Are you getting any JavaScript errors in the console, and if so, what are they? Can you post the entire JavaScript snippet that makes the request, rather than that tiny snippet?

Comment: Thanks Adam!  I just realized that I am, in fact, trying to do what is termed cross-domain requests.  I am new to the technology, but even after reading a few books on xmlhttp implementation, I never came across the fact that issues could arise due to calling your backend from a different domain.  Looking into solutions now...

Comment: Anytime! If you haven't already come across it, [this might help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin).